# What do you call a person who doesn't flinch, regardless on what's happening around them

Tags: single-word-requests

A person who doesn't have any regards for the events of his/her surroundings.

Comment: Do you mean: (1) they don't *notice* what goes on around them; or (2) they are aware of what's going on but nevertheless carry on regardless?

Comment: @Leenbamae19 But which one?

Comment: Number 2 actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bunch of words come to mind:

- *Fearless* implies this person is aware of the events, but not concerned.
- *Unflinching* is the simple one-word adjective form.  It is close to *fearless*, but suggests that even if the person is concerned or afraid, he or she is nonetheless not reactive and does not *show* this concern or fear.
- *Oblivious* implies the person is completely unaware of these events (and hence unreactive).
- *Stoic* is related, but means unemotionally expressive in general: unintimidated by disaster, but also relatively joyless in happier circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

**Imperturbable -- [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/imperturbable)**

> Unable to be upset or excited; calm:
>   *'an imperturbable tranquillity'*

I think **imperturbable** is the best fit, but other synonyms include steely, unflappable, nonchalant, self-possessed.

Comment: I like most of these, though *nonchalant* connotes indifference, which makes sense given its [etymology](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nonchalant); for me, it does not fit well with the other synonyms you've listed.